# How to add digits to different spans with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable which counts an amount of elements:

```
var n = 0;
```

Now, if I make

```
n++;
```

i want to apply this number to different digits:

```
<span class="n">-</span>
<span class="n">-</span>
<span class="n">-</span>
<span class="n">-</span>
```

If i have the number 10, I want:

```
<span class="n">-</span>
<span class="n">-</span>
<span class="n">1</span>
<span class="n">0</span>
```

How can i do this?

**I want to build my own counter.** I can use jQuery / JavaScript or whatever the Web has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var n = 0,
    placeholders = document.getElementsByClassName('n');

function updateView(number) {
    ('' + number).split('').reverse().forEach(function(el, i) {
        placeholders[placeholders.length - i - 1].innerHTML = el;
    });    
}
```

Pass any number in this function and its digits will be placed in proper positions. E.g.:

```
updateView(85); // => --85
```

<sub>(sorry, I don't know how to name this function better)</sub>

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6dZmT/1/

Answer (score 3):

You want to split the digits into an array and assign accordingly:

```
var n =  101;
n++;
var digits = (""+n).split("");
```

Now you have an array `digits` that you can assign out:

```
digits[0] = 1
digits[1] = 0
digits[2] = 2
```

**Update**
Just an idea, instead of creating the SPAN's ahead of time, you could use a container and create them dynamically:

```
<div id="counter"></div>

function setCounter(n) {
    digits = (""+n).split("");
    digits.forEach(function(index){
        $("#counter").append("<span class='digit'>"+index+"</span>");
    });
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/binaryatrocity/Dz22Y/) using the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your example that your counter never goes above four digits. So we can convert the number to a string and build markup by iterating over its characters.

I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/H4wQ8/

But the core of it is this javascript:

```
var n = 0;

function buildCounter(number)
{
    var markup = '';

    var numberString = String(number);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4 - numberString.length; i++)
    {
        markup += '<span class="n">-</span>';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numberString.length; i++)
    {
        markup += '<span class="n">' + numberString[i] + '</span>';
    }

    $('#counter').html(markup);
}

$(function ()
{
    $('#incrementButton').on('click', function ()
    {
        n++;

        buildCounter(n);
    });

    buildCounter(n);
});
```

We use a helper function to build the markup, and jquery to place it in the appropriate container.

Comment: An improvement here would be to split the numberString into an char array.  Check the length and then unshift the default character until the length of the array meets the desired size.  Then we can iterate though that array creating the span tags.  I find that  is is better to stick with the DOM methods for creating the span elements.